# How do i set up a domain with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, godaddy

I have purchased a domain with Goddaddy, I have apache running, and i can access it outside my local network using my IP. Now all i need to know is how do I associate my ip with that domain? Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone needs to host DNS for you. GoDaddy will host it for you if you want, it's a setting on your GoDaddy domain page. After that, you'll need to create a host (or "A") record for your server, which is just a record that matches the name and the IP address.

Link for more info: [GoDaddy DNS Management](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680)

Answer (score 1):

Does your GoDaddy account also come with DNS hosting?  If so then just add a host (A) record into your domain with whatever name you want to use (e.g.- 'www') with your IP (public) address.

If you do not have DNS hosting you will need to either sign up with a DNS host or set up your own DNS server(s).  Buying just a domain from GoDaddy simply gives you the right to that domain name.  You have to have DNS servers that will resolve your domain in order for things to work.